# duvida com impressão web

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf, relatório

Pessoal em meu projeto utilizo MVC, no front end utilizo angular/html/js, etc.
Preciso imprimir um relatorio, qual a melhor forma de fazer? quais ferramentas utilizar?

fiz um teste usando esse codigo:

```
$scope.printReceita = function () {
    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function () {
        var conteudo = document.getElementById('receita').innerHTML,
            tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');

        tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
        tela_impressao.window.print();
        tela_impressao.window.close();
    };
}
```

porem estou tendo dificuldade com a seguinte situação, tenho esse h3:

```
<h3 ng-show="cons_obs.length > 1"> Observações</h3><br />
```

mesmo a variavel cons_obs.length sendo == -1, na impressão aparece "Observações".

imagino que tenha alguma forma/ferramente que seja mais adequado.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Em seu CSS adicione a query `@media print` com a classe `nao-imprimir` e
depois adicione ela aos elementos que você quer esconder durante a impressão.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .nao-imprimir,
  .nao-imprimir * {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>teste</p>
  <h3 class="nao-imprimir">Observações</h3>
  <p>teste</p>
</div>

<button class="nao-imprimir">imprimir</button>
```

Comment: Leandro, continua exibindo "Observações", mesmo no executar codigo da sua resposta

Comment: é por causa do preview, coloque em arquivo html e verifique

Comment: Coloquei um botão de imprimir para demonstrar

Answer (score 1):

Se a opção do `display:none` não funcionar por causa do Angular, vc pode simplesmente mover o `<h3>` para fora da tela de impressão. Dessa forma!

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media print {
    .leftmil {
        position: absolute;
        left: -10000px;
    }
}

@page {
  size: A4;
}
```

```html
<h3>Obsevações Sem left 10000</h3>
<h3 class="leftmil">Obsevações com left 10000 no @print</h3>
```

---

Vc também pode habilitar a "visualização de impressão" pelo Chrome no Dev Tools conforme essa imagem. Ai fica mais fácil para vc ir ajustando seu CSS apenas no formato Print

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa observação tinha esquecido do Angular.